# Why does Django's send_mail not work during testing?

Tags: python, django, email

I have an app that imports a number of user email addresses and creates accounts for them. To have them set their own password, I tried to use django's PasswordResetForm (in django.contrib.auth.forms). The password reset is called as soon as a user account has been created:

```
def reset_password(person):
    form = PasswordResetForm({'email': person.email})
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(from_email='myname@myserver.com')
```

I haven't gotten any further with testing than including a unit test that does this:

```
import password_reset_module
class TestPasswordReset(TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
         p = Person(email='test@test.com')
     def test_send(self):
         password_reset_module.reset_password(p)
```

No assertions, right now I just want to see if there is mail sent at all by monitoring the console in which I run:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Saving the form calls django's send_mail. When running the testcase, the send_mail method returns 1. However, no mails show up in the console. The strange thing is that calling send_mail from django's interactive shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

works fine. Mail shows up in the console. Clicking the forgot my password link in a browser also result in sent mails.

I have also tried the file based email backend to no avail.
Current settings.py email settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myname@myserver.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

Now wondering if I am missing something when calling the password reset, or is there a mailserver configuration issue at hands?

Comment: Can you provide the unittests you are using? Django has a number of e-mail backends that provide dummy output (nothing, to console, etc.) that are used in their own unittests.

Comment: Folks, please note that the `smtpd` module is deprecated (because [it is now considered cruft](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594)) and will disappear in Python 3.12. Use the external module [`aiosmptd`](https://aiosmtpd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably worthwhile trying to turn this into a proper unit test, which of course you can then run as part of your automated test suite. For unit testing, probably the easiest way to check whether the mail was sent (and verify the contents of the mail if required) is to use Django's built-in in memory email backend - you can simply use the outbox attribute on this to get a list of sent mails:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#in-memory-backend

This has the advantage of not requiring any infrastructure setup to support testing email sending, makes it very simple to assert the contents of your email, and this should also make the tests fast (when compared to actually sending the emails to an SMTP server).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, using locmem works without changing anything else. I'll be extra careful testing this feature in production.

Answer (score 15):

### Your config is being overruled

In Section "Email Services", the 
[Django testing documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) says:

> Django's test runner automatically redirects all 
>   Django-sent email to a dummy outbox. [...]
>   During test running, each outgoing email is saved in 
>   `django.core.mail.outbox`. 
>   This is a simple list of all `EmailMessage` instances 
>   that have been sent.

Huh?

**The Django test runner will actually configure a different email backend for you** (called [locmem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#in-memory-backend)).
It is very convenient if you want to do unit-testing only
(without integration with an actual email server), but
very surprising if you don't know it.

(I am not using the Django test runner `manage.py test`,
 but it happens anyway, presumably because I have 
 `pytest-django` installed which magically modifies my `py.test`.)

If you want to override the overriding and use the email configuration
given in your `settings` module, all you need to re-set is the 
setting for the email backend, e.g. like this:

```
@django.test.utils.override_settings(
    EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')
def test_send_email_with_real_SMTP(self):
   ...
```

Comment: `override_settings` now in `django.test`: `from django.test import override_settings`

Comment: Lost a lot of time because of this

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you are running the following command while testing the unit.

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

This command starts up a "dumb" SMTP server that recieves your emails and displays them on the terminal. Try running your site without this DebuggingServer set up and see if the mails are sent.

Here is the reference to the [docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#testing-email-sending)

Comment: Thanks. I think I wasn't quite clear in my question. I want to see my mails processed by the dumb server, but I don't. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mailoutbox](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#mailoutbox) fixture of pytest-django:

> A clean email outbox to which Django-generated emails are sent.
>
> Example

```
from django.core import mail

def test_mail(mailoutbox):
    mail.send_mail('subject', 'body', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'])
    assert len(mailoutbox) == 1
    m = mailoutbox[0]
    assert m.subject == 'subject'
    assert m.body == 'body'
    assert m.from_email == 'from@example.com'
    assert list(m.to) == ['to@example.com']
```